# Chrome DevTools doesn't show<form> element but it exists in source code

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome-devtools

I've encountered strange behaviour of website I recently working on.
It has the code like this (showing a bit simplified for readability):

```
    <div id="svbukleMygtukuKonteineris" class="centerButton">
        <form id="svbukleUzpildymas" action="bukle_irasyti.php" method="post">
        <div class="mygtukai"><a href="index.php" target="_self">atšaukti</a></div>
        <div class="mygtukai"><button type="submit">įrašyti</button></div>
    </div>
```

Seems OK, but when I'm trying to run it on server, browser renders it without <form> element and the form doesn't work (Tried on Opera and Firefox).
Strangest thing is that view-source (ctrl+u) shows code correctly as it supposed to be, but devTools shows it without <form>. By the way, closing </form> is missing also.

Have someone seen behaviour like this? What could be the cause?

These screenshots were taken at the same time

Here's the view-source screenshot:
[image: view-source screenshot]

And here's devTools screenshot with  missing after id="svbukleMygtukuKonteineris"
[image]

Comment: You haven't closed the form with `</form>` Try that and see what happens

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed the case!

Comment: Install linters on your IDE, errors like these will be visible....

Answer (score 0):

For those who will stuck in situation like this - it seems that I accidentally deleted closing tag of <form> element of previous form. So, the browser removed the second opening <form> tag to avoid errors.
Anyway, strange that view-source showed it as existent.